# Regarding Sql query

Tags: mysql

```
AHLBLOCKNO  AHLSLNOHHD  SLNOMEMBER  NAME        GENDERID
0193        0073        001         BABLA      MALE
0193        0073        002         VINAYBHAI   MALE
0193        0073        004         SANJANABEN FEMALE
0193        0073        005         VISHALBHAI  MALE
0193        0105        001         ASHVINBHAI  MALE
0193        0105        003         PARESHBHAI  MALE
0193        0105        002         ARUNABEN    FEMALE
0193        0143        001         CHHAKABHAI  MALE
0193        0143        003         FAKIRBHAI   MALE
0193        0143        004         SUMITRABEN  FEMALE
0193        0143        005         PANKAJBHAI  MALE
0193        0143        002         VANITABEN   FEMALE
0193        0143        007         PRIYANSHAN  FEMALE
0193        0162        001        RAMANBHAI    MALE
0193        0162        003        KAVITABEN    FEMALE
0193        0162        005         SANJAYBHAI  MALE
0193        0162        004        SUNILBHAI    MALE
0193        0162        002        BIPINBHAI    MALE
0193        9999        001        bhimjibhai   MALE
```

In the above table i want to get such `AHLSLNOHHD` in which none of genderid is equal to female.

Output expected is:

```
AHLBLOCKNO  AHLSLNOHHD  SLNOMEMBER  NAME        GENDERID
0193        9999        001        bhimjibhai   MALE
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you don't invest time in showing your effort, you'll receive downvotes instead of help here

Comment: I am new to sql Sir and had tried a lot with limited knowledge......post to learn some new concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
# SELECT all columns from your table  
SELECT t1.* FROM tablename t1 
   # LEFT OUTER JOIN to same table 
   LEFT JOIN tablename t2 ON 
      # WITH SAME AHLSLNOHHD
      t1.AHLSLNOHHD = t2.AHLSLNOHHD 
      # AND where GENDERID is FEMALE
      AND t2.GENDERID = 'FEMALE'
 # NOW only consider rows where no such join (with female) could be found:
 WHERE t2.AHLSLNOHHD IS NULL
```

Comment: No Sir It didn't work. The query I want is to pair the AHLBLOCKNO  with AHLSLNOHHD  then in each unique pair need to find that does any of the SLNOMEMBER in that pair has GENDERID equal to female? If yes then left that pair and show the rest of pairs. or in otherway i want to findout the pairs which has all SLNOMEMBER  are MALE.

Comment: well... would have been nice if you explained that in your question... Please edit your question to highlight what you really need the query to do...

Comment: What that join does is it selects all rows where no Female record exists for this AHLSNOHHD

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.AHLBLOCKNO  NOT IN (SELECT AHLBLOCKNO FROM Table1 where GENDERID = 'FEMALE')
```